# Is there a most efficient speed to travel in space with reference to time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, software, space-travel

I was thinking hypothetically, a ship traveling to a distant star system with something like food wants to get to the system as fast as possible. The trick is, we want to travel as fast as possible in relation to the people in the opposite star system. Is it really best to travel as close to the speed as light as possible (essentially go as fast as possible) or is there some speed limit in which going faster will actually make observers see you traveling slower due to time dilation?
I wrote a pretty brute force program (as my calculus is too bad to try break up the time dilation equation) to see if there was a velocity that you arrive at a position later than traveling slower:

> ```
>    public const double c = 299792458;
>    //m/s
>    static void Main(string[] args)
>    {
>        double distance = 0;
>        double time = 0;
>        double previoustime = 0;
>        double previousObserverTime = double.MaxValue;
>        double finalVelocity = 0;
>        distance = c * 36000; //Just some large distance
>        for (double velocity = 1; velocity < c; velocity += 1)
>        {
>            time = distance / velocity;
>            double dilation = find_dilation(velocity, time);
>            if (dilation > previousObserverTime)
>            {
>                finalVelocity = velocity - 1;
>                break;
>            }
>            else
>            {
>                previoustime = time;
>                previousObserverTime = dialation;
>            }
>        }
>        Console.WriteLine("Velocity = " + finalVelocity + "m/s");
>        Console.WriteLine("Observer time = " + previousObserverTime);
>        Console.WriteLine("Pilot Time = " + previoustime);
>        Console.ReadKey();
>    }
>    static public double find_dilation(double velocity, double time)
>    {
>        double c = 299792458;
>        double c_sqrd = Math.Pow(c, 2);
>        double dilation = time / Math.Sqrt( 1 - (Math.Pow(velocity, 2)/c_sqrd));
>        return dilation;
>    }
> ```
>
> }

I ran this program and found that at velocity 211985278 m/s, the observer time it took for a pilot to travel this distance was either the same or slower as the next interval at 211985279 m/s. I'm assuming that means at this point, this is where the slope of the curve of the time dilation is x.

Am I on the right track here? could some speed around 211985278 m/s be the most efficient speed to travel at for observers? Or am I not understanding how these things work?

Edit: I'm really not interested in whether my numbers or code are correct. Just really curious if there is something like efficient travel, or if going as close to the speed of light is the answer to get somewhere the quickest possible for observers.

Comment: This seems to be a check-my-work type of question, which is not what this site is for.

Comment: To get there as fast as possible you go as fast as possible. If you're program is giving you alternate results then you either (a) have a bug in the code or (b) misunderstand the physics. I'd guess the latter because you don't need to bother with time-dilation if you do the computation in the rest frame of the destination.

Comment: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a computer program to check this. Just think about it. Time dilation never comes into play. There is only one velocity that matters, as you said, and that is your velocity relative to the destination, particularly its projection onto the separation vector between you and the destination. No matter which frame, this is the fastest. For you - where the distance has shortened, and thus the travel time has also shortened, and also for the outside observers, where you are travelling faster.

Answer (score 0):

Moving faster will simply get you there faster...

Also, moving closer to the speed of light should make it feel as though it takes even less time (to the passengers) according to time dilation.

Time dilation won't really affect the view of an outsider, that is, they will continue to experience regular time and will see you going at a speed relative to them.